# Sending value to nested element in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following HTML to make an accordion:

```
{{isExpandAllOpen}}  // Present in the scope of the calling page
<li class="row" ng-repeat="test in AllTests">
    <div vh-accordion-group panel-class="panel-info">
        <div vh-accordion-header> </div>
        <div vh-accordion-body>   </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

In vhAccordionHeader.js we have the following code:

```
home.directive("vhAccordionHeader", ['version', function(version) {
return {
    require: '^vhAccordionGroup',
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'EA',
    transclude: 'element',
    templateUrl: "JS/HomeModule/Directives/vhAccordion/vhAccordionHeader.html?v=" + version
};
}]);

home.directive("vhAccordionAssignId", function() {
    return {
        require: '^vhAccordionGroup',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, vhAccordionGroupController) {

        scope.isOpen = true;
    }
};
});
```

in AccordionHeader.html

```
<div class="panel-heading">
<h4 class="panel-title">
    <a ng-click="isOpen = !isOpen" data-toggle="collapse" onclick=" return false; " vh-accordion-assign-id>
        <i class="pull-left glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up': isOpen, 'glyphicon-chevron-down': !isOpen}" style="margin: -2px 10px 0 0"></i><span ng-transclude></span>
    </a>
</h4>
```

the isOpen variable controls the expand/collapse all functionality. 
Since I want to implement a expand/collapse all functionality, using the isExpandAllOpen to be equal to IsOpen, when expanding all button is used. 
I cannot find a way to assign isExpandAllOpen to isOpen as it is a diferent directive. 
TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't specify isolated scope for your `vhAccordionAssignId` directive you an get access to `isExpandAllOpen` via scope inheritance. Simply read `scope.isExpandAllOpen`. Mind that scope inheritance will work for reading only.

Now you want to be notified when it got changed? Put a watcher in your link function

```
scope.$watch('isExpandAllOpen', function(newVal){
    scope.isOpen = newVal;
    //do additional stuff if required
});
```

Comment: off topic, is that a real klashnikov in ur DP ?

Comment: @ShankyJain nope :) it's an electric model that shoots 5mm plastic balls. It looks exactly the same but weights a little more